# i can't not run a base python code using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Please help checking with my code

```
import pandas as pandas
import numpy as np
import random as rd

data1 = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\quynh.tranngoc\Desktop\B32_DownloadTable_20230508_100440.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df.head(n=6)
```

the platform i was using is jupyter note book, however the system keep saying i am having this errror.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data1 = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\quynh.tranngoc\Desktop\B32_DownloadTable_20230508_100440.csv")
      2 df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
      3 df.head(n=6)

NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined
```

Please help me, i don't know what i did wrong!! Thank you so much for your support

i have inserted the pandas eventhough i already did in the pass, i also retyping multiple times but the result still remain no change

Comment: Did you run the first cell (the one with imports)?

Comment: also, please format your code and errors properly within code blocks.

Comment: problem solved, thank you so much. The 1st line has not yet been run